# Modifying user defined Keywords which have hard coded parameters in Robot framework

Tags: python, robotframework

**Scenario :**

I have certain keywords , which were using hard coded values in them e.g.

```
PUT Method
    [Arguments]     ${token}      ${PUT_ACTION_URI}     ${req_data}     ${status_code}   
    ${second}     fetch from right   ${PUT_ACTION_URI}     /v2/ip/
    ${PUT_ACTION_URI}     set variable if   '${admin_flag}'=='True'      /v2/ip/admin/${second}      ${PUT_ACTION_URI}
    [Return]    ${responsejsondata}
```

Here  **/v2/ip** is hard coded

Now this value can be anything i.e.  **/v2/ip** to **/v3/ip**  or **/v3.1/ip**

To handle this , I can think off

1. Create seprate KW for /v3/ip or /v3.1/ip
2. Create a separate branch for each v2/V3/V3.1 and replace the V2/V3 accordinggly .
3. Create a Global variable and replace /v2/ip by that Global variable

i Have around 400 KWs where /v2/ip is being used atleast 3 times in each file , following any of the three methods will involve some amount of manual work.

if decorators can be used here ?

where they can just modify the /v2/ip  in underlying KW on run time based on flag set.

Any other approach is also welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Create global variable with default value & use it in code (like test_data.robot)

**Ex:**

```
${VERSION}    v2
```

**Code:**

```
PUT Method
    [Arguments]     ${token}      ${PUT_ACTION_URI}     ${req_data}     ${status_code}   
    ${second}     fetch from right   ${PUT_ACTION_URI}     /${VERSION}/ip/
    ${PUT_ACTION_URI}     set variable if   '${admin_flag}'=='True'      /${VERSION}/ip/admin/${second}      ${PUT_ACTION_URI}
    [Return]    ${responsejsondata}
```

Now users can modify ${VERSION} in run time also

```
robot -v VERSION:v3 suite.robot
```

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways to achieve this in robot framework.

#### 1. Using global variable and assigning variable at run time. (This approach is good if you have less variables)

`${VERSION}    v2`

and provide value at run time using robot -v VERSION:v3 suite.robot

```
PUT Method
[Arguments]     ${token}      ${PUT_ACTION_URI}     ${req_data}     ${status_code}   
${second}     fetch from right   ${PUT_ACTION_URI}     /${VERSION}/ip/
${PUT_ACTION_URI}     set variable if   '${admin_flag}'=='True'      /${VERSION}/ip/admin/${second}      ${PUT_ACTION_URI}
[Return]    ${responsejsondata}
```

#### 2. Using scalar file approach (This approach is good if you have more variables)

- Create external file lets say : scalars.py

scalars.py

  `VERSION=2.1
  VARIABLE_1="ANY VALUE IN THIS FORMAT"
  ...
  ...
  VARIABLE_N="ANY VALUE IN THIS FORMAT"`
* Import this file into robot in `Variables` section.

- The scope of these variables are also global

### CODE

*** Settings ***

Library              You_Other_Custom_libraries

Variables            Scalars.py

*** Test Cases ***

```
PUT Method
[Arguments]     ${token}      ${PUT_ACTION_URI}     ${req_data}     ${status_code}   
${second}     fetch from right   ${PUT_ACTION_URI}     /${VERSION}/ip/
${PUT_ACTION_URI}     set variable if   '${admin_flag}'=='True'      /${VERSION}/ip/admin/${second}      ${PUT_ACTION_URI}
[Return]    ${responsejsondata}
```

## Based on edit of your question (other approach)

#### 3. using sed command to replace string

Write a script :

- Create copy of your test-case files (To Keep original files safe)
- Replace content using **sed** command

  - ex. `sed 's/<str_to_replace>/<str_with_replace>/g' *.robot`
- Execute test cases
- Delete copied files (to save space)

#### Repeat above steps to re-run test cases

Comment: @pankaj mishra, Please comment if you need any more information on this

Comment: any other way apart from replacing /v2/ip with ${VERSION}?

Comment: Defining a variable is way to provide values dynamically, Is there any specific requirement you have?

Comment: one inappropriate way is, write a script that copy (to keep original file safe) all test-case files and replace content using **sed** command ex. `sed 's/<to_replace>/<with_replace>/g' *.robot`, execute test cases and then delete copied files

Comment: Thanks , looks like global variable is only option , will focus on that